# Swift: How to save data to a certain date

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save data based on the day the data was recorded (e.g. User had 5 apples to eat on the 29/07/2016).

I cant find a way in the documentation to save the data without creating a calendar event. Would the data have to be stored in an array containing both the number of apples eaten and the day the apples were eaten using a struct? and how could the data then be accessed? would it be through the use of global variables?

Comment: how long do you want to save it for? how are you going to use it once it's saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

You would create a dictionary like this:

```
var applesPerDay = [NSDate: Int]()
```

You would set the value for a day like this:

```
applesPerDay[NSDate()] = 5
```

You could print all values sorted in chronological order like this:

```
for key in applesPerDay.keys.sort({$0.compare($1) == .OrderedAscending}) {
    //you may want to format the date
    print("On day \(key) I ate \(applesPerDay[key]!) apples")
}
```

If you need to persist the data you could use [NSUserDefaults](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Quick few questions;

1) How could I make these accessible to all view controllers?

2) Would this work if the data is to be recorded automatically e.g. In viewDidLoad of a ViewController, would each days information be unique if I just added the code you have in your answer? (assuming that the '5' will be different each day)

Comment: 1. You could save it in NSUserDefaults (many global variables are usually a symptom for poor software design)  2. Yes, it would be unique, but only for each tic (fraction of a second), not for each day. If you want to make it unique for days, use a [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) and save the day as a string (use a `[String: String]`dictionary)

Comment: 1. If it is bad practice to save many global variables is there another way around it? (e.g. deleting input that is older than 60 days). And finally, how would you access the data for a certain day e.g. if you wanted to find out how many apples were eaten on 29/07/2016. Thank you for your help, ill mark your answer as correct

Comment: There is no global solution for bad software design. You have to find the right architecture for your specific case. Deleting old data out of a global variable won't make it cleaner. 2. If you used `NSDate` keys, find all keys that are in the time interval of that day, if you used `String`, format the date the same way and just do `applesPerDay[formattedDayString]`

Comment: So would something like 'If (NSDate == 29/07/2016) { print(applesPerDay) }' work?

Comment: no, since `29/07/2016` is not a NSDate, you would have to convert it first. Also you probably want to do `print(applesPerDay[convertedNSDate]) `

Answer (score 2):

For what you're looking at, the recommended approach would be to use `CoreData`. `NSUserDefaults` is designed to allow you to keep relatively small bits of "configuration" data.

`CoreData` allows you to define an object hierarchy and then do searching, sorting, and all kinds of SQL-style queries on the stored data.

Check around for one of the many tutorials, for most purposes I suggest one of Ray Wenderlich's, such as this one [Intro to CoreData](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

Note: I am not, nor have I ever been, affiliated with Ray Wenderlich :)

Comment: Follow up question; are coredata entries global? If not is there a way to make them global?